# Vue.js: The view doesn't update after data is updated?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mvvm, vue.js, axios

```
<div id="app">
<h1> News Aggregator </h1>
<div v-for="CurNews in news">
<div id="title">
<h1>{{CurNews.title}}</h1>
</div>
<div id="description">
<p>{{CurNews.description}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>








<script>
const API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXX";
const url = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?";



const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data:{
    news: [{
    title:"ABC", description: "VXAEW"
    }]
    },
mounted(){
    axios.get("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-times-of-india&sortBy=top&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXX").then(function(response){
    this.news = response.data.articles;
    //app.$set(this.news, response.data.articles);
    console.log(response.data.articles);
    }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
    })
}
});

</script>
```

The view does not update. Also, whenever I try to access the response/news object through the console, I get "Reference Error: response/news in not defined". The AJAX call works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

In your axios request `.then` sucess callback `this` is not pointing to the vue instance since you are using a normal function syntax, use fat arrow `=>` function syntax instead like this:

```
mounted(){
    axios.get("your URL").then((response) => {
    this.news = response.data.articles;
    console.log(response.data.articles);
    }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Or else declare a var `vm` at the start of your mounted block pointing the  vue instance like this:

```
mounted(){
    var vm = this;
    axios.get("your URL").then(function(response) {
    vm.news = response.data.articles;
    console.log(response.data.articles);
    }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div v-for="CurNews in news">
        <div id="title">
        <h1>{{CurNews.title}}</h1>
    </div>
```

id is unique, you can use class. The data attribute should be a function.

```
data(): {
 news: [{
  title:"ABC", description: "VXAEW"
  }]
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem... data must be a function for vue component instances

Answer (score 0):

You can try using arrow function like:

```js
fetch("/static/data/data_table.json", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
          }
        )
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
          }).then ((json) => {
          this.resultJson = json
        }).catch( (ex) => {
        })
```